# Weak Law of Large Numbers Confusion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If I have a sequence of IID random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ with $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\mu$  then the WLLN implies that $\bar{X}_n$ converges to $\mu$. This is where my confusion lies. It is my understanding that RV are deterministic functions $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where the random component comes from $\omega\in\Omega$. If we are defining $\bar{X}_n(\omega)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i({\omega})$, if $X_i$ are iid then it is not assumed that $X_i(\omega)=X_j(\omega)$ so have an average of different values. When we apply the weak law of large numbers in real life we take the average of a sequence of iid random variables, but doesn't the WLLN require that the RV's be evaluated in the same $\omega$, why are we able to assume that this holds. Am I understanding the WLLN wrong?

Comment: Everything you’ve said is correct (to be specific, WLLN implies convergence _in probability_). As to why we can assume we always have the same $\omega$), this is just something you have to get used to. Think of it like this; $\omega$ is determined at the beginning of time, and then all possible random events in the universe are determined from that one $\omega$.

Comment: the $\bar X_n$ doesn't converge in value, it just converge in probability. It means that for any chosen $\epsilon > 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity the probability that $|\bar X_n-\mu|<\epsilon$ becomes bigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify a bit more about the role of the $\omega$ here: in this setup generally the space $\Omega$ is defined as a space of sequences and each $X_i$ is the $i$-th projection of each $\omega$.

A concrete way to define it: set a probability measure in $\mathbb{R}$, then this measure will represent the law of each $X_i$. Then the infinite product space $\Omega:=\mathbb{R}^{\infty }:=\prod_{n\in \mathbb N }\mathbb{R}$ can be given with a probability measure induced by the individual probability measures of each $\mathbb{R}$ probability space.

Then, as advised at the beginning, each $\omega\in \Omega$ is just an arbitrary real valued sequence. Then when you evaluates something like $\Pr[\bar X_n\in A ]$ you are measuring a set (of sequences) in $\Omega$. Then informally the weak law of large numbers say us that as $n$ increases then the amount of sequences in $\Omega$ such that the mean of it $n$-th first values are far away of $\mu$ becomes arbitrarily small in measure (i.e., in probability). Formally it assert that

$$
\forall \epsilon >0,\, \forall \delta >0,\,\exists N\in \mathbb N,\, \forall n\geqslant N: \Pr [|\bar X_n-\mu|\geqslant \delta ]<\epsilon 
$$

where $\mu:=\operatorname{E}[X_1]$ and $\Pr $ is the probability measure in $\Omega $.

In summary: each $\omega $ represent intuitively a "random sample" (a sequence of values), and remember that $\Pr [X\in A]:=\Pr (\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega )\in A\})=\Pr(X^{-1}(A))$, in this case $X=|\bar X_n-\mu|$ and $A=[\delta ,\infty )$, so we are measuring the probability that a random sample belongs to some subset of $\Omega $, in this case we are measuring the probability that, given a sequence, the mean of it $n$-th first values deviates from $\mu$ more than a given amount.

Comment: what do you mean by each each $X_i$ is the $i$-th projection of each ω.

Comment: I mean that: let $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ the identity function on $\mathbb{R}$, that is, $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then give to $\Bbb R$ the probability measure of $X_1$. Then you can construct a probability space $\Omega=\Bbb R^\infty$ with a probability measure on it such that $X_i(\omega)=\omega_i$ for each $\omega=(\omega _1,\omega _2,\ldots ,\omega _i,\ldots )\in \Omega $. Then the sequence $\{X_i\}_{i\in \mathbb N}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. r.v. on $\Omega $, and the law of each $X_i$ is the same probability measure that you give to each $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: there are textbooks with this construction detailed, by example the book of Robert Ash *Probability and measure* or the book of Achim Klenke.

Comment: Then can this structure of the sample space be extended to convergence to a random variable but pointwise where each sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$  corresponds to a $X_{n}(\omega)\rightarrow \mu(\omega)=X^{\infty}(\omega)$? Where $X^{\infty}(\omega)$ is just generic notation for the pointwise convergence of the given sequence $\omega$.

Comment: @Noe I dont understand what you mean. There are conditions where $\bar X_i\to \mu$ pointwise, this is what we call an strong law of large numbers, maybe this help you to clarify.

Comment: I am more confused with the idea of thinking of the underlying space as a sequence when it comes to having a sequence of random functions converging to another function: 

$X_{n}(\omega)\rightarrow X(\omega)$. If $\omega$ is a sequence then what does $X(\omega)$ mean in either convergence almost surely or in probability, when $X$  is suppose to take a scalar as an input.

Comment: @Noe I dont understand what you mean. The domain of a r.v. is an abstract space $\Omega$, it is in general not assumed to be a space of scalars or so. What we assume is that the codomain of a r.v. is $\Bbb R$. To solve your doubts I think it will be better to read the references that I give about the construction of the answer, or open a different question in mse